# What happens if you call a blocking method within an async call?

Tags: .net, async-await, task-parallel-library

If you are making an aysnc-enabled application, and you have to interact with a 3rd-party library which only provides blocking methods, what happens when an `async` method blocks?

An easy example would be in .Net Framework, `Socket.Receive` lets you set a timeout but then blocks. If a 3rd-party lib wraps this and I call it within an asyncronous methoddoes it simply mean whichever thread the runtime assigns to the `Task` is blocked? Could it block other tasks or have other side-effects?

Comment: Spoiler: nothing good. Further reading https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, you are answering a wrong question. :-)

Comment: I'll clarify this is nothing related to UI since that's come up - assume it's a server application

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong to block in an `async` method.  There are implications, though.

If you block in an `async void` method, which is invoked by an UI event, you will also block the UI thread and make your UI unresponsive.

When you block in a `async Task` method, or in any `Task` you will of course block the thread that currently runs this part of the method or this task.  If you run concurrently many instances of this task, or if your method gets executed concurrently (for example, it is a service method that gets called by many clients), you can exhaust the thread-pool.  This can prevent other tasks from running, or other clients to call your service.

If you want to avoid the latter case, it might be worthy to run this blocking method in a [long-running Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcreationoptions?view=netcore-3.1).  The current implementation in .Net will create a separate thread for this task, thus not blocking a thread from the thread pool.

Comment: I had thought long-running tasks were considered a bit old-fashioned/irrelevant these days in an `async` - based application. Hapy to be corrected though.

Comment: Well, they are not recommended for mundane stuff that is expected to be completed in a handful of milliseconds.  The overhead of creating and disposing of a thread is there.  But, if you expect a blocking operation to run for a long time, long-running tasks are there for you. :-)

Answer (score 1):

> If a 3rd-party lib wraps this and I call it within an asyncronous methoddoes it simply mean whichever thread the runtime assigns to the Task is blocked?

Yes. At best it blocks your task thread and at worst if you were in any `Synchronization Context` (`Desktop GUI` or `ASP.NET Request Threads before .Net Core`) you'll be stuck in deadlock!

> Could it block other tasks or have other side-effects?

If you wrap blocking method by thread named **T** which is defined like `Task.Run(/* Blocking method */)` it will block **T**.

Comment: For these purposes does `Synchromization context` basically mean "several tasks using the same underlying thread"? If so I can see how that thread being blocked by Task A is going to deadlock other tasks. But that's what the blog in the comments to my question is talking about right?

Comment: @Mr.Boy: Not exactly, sync context dosn't need many tasks to being deadlocked, just one is enough! It basically says to inner task: after finishing your task you must only call me (and no one else) to let you being complete. If inner task was blocking, sync context blocked too and no one can release them. Beware that it's not limited to UI, it can happen on server too. It's explained in detail in that link you mentioned